# Javascript function do not work when called from code behind(C#)

Tags: javascript, c#

I have this javascript function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function montaDataSubstituicaoPrestador(dt_exclusao) {

            var arrData = dt_exclusao.split('/');
            var exclusaoFormatada = arrData[1] + '-' + arrData[0] + '-' + arrData[2];
            var dias = parseInt(prazoSubPrestador);
            var novaData = new Date(arrData[2], arrData[1] - 1, arrData[0]);

            novaData.setDate(novaData.getDate() + dias);

            hoje = new Date(novaData)
            dia = hoje.getDate()
            mes = hoje.getMonth()
            ano = hoje.getFullYear()
            if (dia < 10)
                dia = "0" + dia

            if ((mes + 1) < 10)
                mes = "0" + (mes + 1);

            if (ano < 2000)
                ano = "19" + ano

            var dt = dia + "/" + (mes) + "/" + ano;

            document.getElementById('lblPrazoSubsAns').innerHTML 
                                             = "Prazo de substituição: " + dt;
        }
    </script>
```

And i have this call from code behind:

```
ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;
cs.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), 
         "MontaDataExclusaoPrazoANS", 
         "montaDataSubstituicaoPrestador(" + calDataExclusao.Date + ")", true);
```

This do not work. Nothing happens. What must I do?

If I do this way, work but the parameter is null:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(),
               "_montaDataSubstituicaoPrestador", 
               "montaDataSubstituicaoPrestador(null);", true);
```

But, if change do not work. Do not accept concatenate character:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(),
               "_montaDataSubstituicaoPrestador", 
               "montaDataSubstituicaoPrestador(" + nova_data + ");", true);
```

This way, i have this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Why?

Comment: There is a syntax error in your script, `prazoSubPrestador` is not defined

Comment: ....and that syntax error woud stop execution of JavaScript after that error

Comment: @Jaco, You have reason. I will correct and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change your function from

```
ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;
            cs.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "MontaDataExclusaoPrazoANS", "montaDataSubstituicaoPrestador(" + calDataExclusao.Date + ")", true)
```

to

```
ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;
            cs.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "MontaDataExclusaoPrazoANS", "montaDataSubstituicaoPrestador('" + calDataExclusao.Date + "')", true)
```

and for

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "_montaDataSubstituicaoPrestador", "montaDataSubstituicaoPrestador(" + nova_data + ");", true);
```

to

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "_montaDataSubstituicaoPrestador", "montaDataSubstituicaoPrestador('" + nova_data + "');", true);
```

Because javascript doesn't understand direct argument as a parameter you have to specify it with single quote while concatenate.
 Hope it will work

Comment: You put two approaches. What do you recommend?

Comment: No no actually I have just corrected your function. But argument with any function from back end for javascript needs single quote. So DOM can easily understand to parse your function.

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

`protected void btnSUbmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string check = "hello";
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myScript", "montaDataSubstituicaoPrestador('" + check + "')", true);
        }`